# Finding ALL indexes of elements in nested List

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing, nested-loops, tic-tac-toe

Tic tac toe where the board is represented as [['x', 'x', 'x'], [' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ']]

we would like to identify all the empty squares on board. The empty square locations on the board will be returned as a (row, column) tuple.

Complete the function empty_squares(board), which returns the list of tuples, where each tuple is the (row, column) of the empty square.

This is what i have so far, it returns the tuples of all squares but i only want the empty ones.

```
def empty_squares(board):
    check = ' '
    target_cell_list = []
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            target_cell_list.append((i, j))
    return target_cell_list
```

Comment: You can try an `if` statement to wrap around your `.append`.

Comment: What have you tried to actually find only the empty fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slightly change your approach to make it more "pythonic". Avoiding nested for-loops you can use list comprehension with built-in `enumerate` statement. So `empty_sqares` can look like this:

```
def empty_sqares(board):
    return [(row_idx, col_idx) for row_idx, row in enumerate(board)
            for col_idx, item in enumerate(row) if item == ' ']
```

Most important think to figure out is what `enumerate` does. In short it iterates through `iterable` (ex. list, list of lists, lists of objects etc.) and for each element returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from iterating over iterable. Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

So what is going on in code:

- `for row_idx, row in enumerate(board)` iterate through rows in `board`. Because items of `board` (rows) are lists, consecutive results of `enumerate(board)` are row index (`row_idx`) and row content (`row` which is list of strings). So for for example, first "iteration" result of `enumerate(board)` will be: `row_idx = 0` `row = ['x', 'x', 'x']`.
- `for col_idx, item in enumerate(row)` iterate through `row`, pick each element of a `row` and assign it to `item`. So for example, first "iteration" result of `enumerate(row)` will be: `col_idx = 0` `item = 'x'`.
- `if item == ' '` performs check if picked character (in your case you have two options`'x'`' or `' '`) equals single space ...
- ... and if check is true, tuple `(row_idx, col_idx)` is formed.
- Whole thing is enclosed inside square brackets `[..]` to make *list* of tuples. But remember, new tuple is appended to result only if above condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

## Add the if statement

```
def empty_squares(board):
    check = ' '
    target_cell_list = []
    for i in range(len(board)):
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            if board[i][j] == " ":
                target_cell_list.append((i, j))
    return target_cell_list
```